# Creating a new table in phpMyAdmin but clicking a submit button in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a new list in phpMyAdmin when the user clicks the "create new list" button on the web page but can't seem to get it working.
When I click "create new list" I get this error -

```
not working1 not working 3
Notice: Undefined variable: tablename in /strath-cis/2014/WEBSITE!/create_new_table.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined variable: tablename in /strath-cis/2014/WEBSITE!/create_new_table.php on line 22
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(id, tablename) VALUES(Null, '')' at line 1
```

Here's the code

```
<?php
session_start();

$host=""; // Host name
$user_name=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password


echo "not working1";

// Create connection
mysql_connect("$host", "$user_name", "$password")or die("cannot connect");


// Check connection
$con=mysql_connect("","","iftercha") or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

    // Create table
 // $tablename = $_POST['tablename'];

echo "not working 3";
  $query ="CREATE TABLE $tablename (id, tablename) 
    VALUES(Null, '$tablename')";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: where u defined ur table name ?

Comment: Are you actually trying to edit the PHPMySQL application or do you mean MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to uncomment the declaration of `$tablename`

```
// Create table
$tablename = $_POST['tablename'];
```

Additional you really should implement some kind of prevention against SQL-injections. Using mysqli prepared-statements or `mysql_real_escape_string` on your `$tablename` are a good start.

Example for escaping:

```
$tablename = $_POST['tablename'];
$tablename_escaped = mysql_real_escape_string($tablename);
$query ="CREATE TABLE '$tablename_escaped' (id, tablename) VALUES(null, '$tablename_escaped')";
```

Example for using mysqli:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("yourhost.com", "username", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$query = "CREATE TABLE ? (id, tablename) VALUES(null, ?)";

if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query))) {
    die("Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error);
}

$tablename = @$_POST['tablename'];

if (!$stmt->bind_param("ss", $tablename, $tablename)) {
    die("Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    die("Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
}
```

[PHP: mysqli - Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)